# Point of Dynastic Allies

Tags: crusader-kings-2

What is the point of having dynastic allies? I can't call them into war like regular allies, nor do they ever voluntarily help me out.

The one benefit to them I've noticed is that the AI can call dynastic allies into conflicts, so all my dynastic vassals can call each other into conflicts, allowing my vassals to expand my realm for me much more easily than they could by themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Members of your dynasty behave like any other allies. The reason you couldn't call yours to war is that they are your vassals. You get levies from them instead.

If a member of your dynasty was ruler of another realm, for example, you would be able to call them to war.

Thete are advantages to landing dynasty members. Members of the same dynasty get a small opinion bonus toward each other, so they will be slightly more loyal as vassals. The downside is they often have claims on your titles.

Landed dynasty members also increase your dynasty's prestige. A highly prestigious dynasty means children of that dynasty are born with prestige- always an advantage.

Comment: They always provide with their obligated levies though. I thought the point of calling armies into war was they would use their personal troops, allowing you to get their total manpower not just part of it. Is there no get like I do with foreign allies?

Comment: @TahsisClaus The point of calling allies to war is they join your war. Your vassals are a part of your wars whether they like it or not. When you call a foreign ruler into your war he can call up of all the troops in his demense, just like you can, but he can only call up a fraction of his vassal's troops, just like you.

Comment: They give you levies because they have to, not because they have a personal stake in the war. The point of calling in an ally is giving them a personal stake and thus more motivation to commit their own troops.

Comment: It seems weird that my vassal can get more troops than me from a mutual ally is all, as if my vassal calls in another of my vassals, the vassal called into their war will provide their full troop support, other factors notwithstanding.

Levies and allies can't even be considered the same thing since allies fight in the war autonomously.

Comment: Another important point: when you get vassal troops, you get to use them as you see fit. Allies are under AI control. I've been frustrated many times by the poor strategy of my allies.

Comment: Here is a picture of the phenomenon: http://imgur.com/3Bwu9c3. When my vassals decide to attack someone, they ALL attack that person. The total troops fielded is much larger than even my total vassal levies, and I can not call in the allies like that. It seems weird they have stronger allegiance to each other than me (they still can't gang me though since I assume a dynastic alliance won't be honored if it breaks another one). At the very least, it has allowed my vassals under me to acquire almost as much territory as me, which is pretty nice.

Comment: @TahsisClaus Your vassals can call each other because they are all in the same realm. They put 100% into it because it's their decision. When you take their levy contribution for war, they're forced into it. There are upsides and downsides to both.

Comment: @TahsisClaus Though if you're interested in vassals who you call to war as if they were allies, consider playing as a Tribal realm.